# creating pandas multiindex based on CustomBusinessHour start

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
             datetime    price  tickvol      bid      ask
0 2016-10-11 12:24:03  2130.25        1  2130.00  2130.25
1 2016-10-11 13:31:03  2130.25        1  2130.00  2130.25
...
```

I have a CustomBusinessHour that looks like this:

```
cbh = CustomBusinessHour(start='13:30', end='13:15', weekmask='Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu')
```

I was hoping that I could create a new index level using the start timestamp of the custom business hour, but I'm having trouble getting things working.

What I'm hoping to get to is something like:

```
                cbh            datetime    price  tickvol      bid      ask
2016-10-10 13:30:00 2016-10-11 12:24:03  2130.25        1  2130.00  2130.25
2016-10-11 13:30:00 2016-10-11 13:31:03  2130.25        1  2130.00  2130.25
```

Comment: Can you show an example where the desired output is the result of your input?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Wouldn't that be the answer to my question?

Comment: What I'm saying is that your output did not come from your input because the dates don't match.

Comment: They are the correct desired output dates. The CustomBusinessHour sets a start of the day at 13:30 and end of day at 13:15 (23.75 hours spanning midnight).  The dates are in the same calendar day, but different a different custom business day.  I'd like to create an index level on the start of the custom business day, but can't find a way to determine the start of the custom business day when given the timestamp.

Comment: Got it, `13:30` and `13:15` are so close that I inverted them. I don't have an answer unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. It works, but could probably be improved. It appears that `CustomBusinessHour` does not directly expose any way to determine if a time is in or out.

```
def session_start(ts, cbh):
    """Given a timestamp and a CustomBusinessHour, return the session start
    timestamp"""
    assert type(ts) == pd.Timestamp
    spans = spans_midnight(cbh)
    t = ts.time()
    if spans:
        if cbh.end <= t < cbh.start:
            return pd.NaT
        elif t < cbh.start:
            # this timestamp is part of the previous calendar day session
            ts = ts.replace(day=ts.day - 1)
    else:
        if cbh.end <= t or t < cbh.start:
            return pd.NaT

    return ts.replace(hour=cbh.start.hour, minute=cbh.start.minute,
                      second=cbh.start.second,
                      microsecond=cbh.start.microsecond)


# assuming df looks similar to the one in the problem statement...
cbh = CustomBusinessHour(start='06:30', end='13:15',
                         weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri')
df['session_start'] = df.index.map(lambda x: session_start(x, cbh))
df.dropna(how='all', subset=['session_start'], inplace=True)
df.set_index(['session_start', df.index], drop=True, inplace=True)
```